# How to remove the ngx-color-picker package(version 13) from my angular project (version 15) and how can we install the version 14 ngx-color-picker

Tags: angular, color-picker, angular15

I am not able to implement the ngx-color-picker(v.13) in my Angular (v.15) so can any one tell me

i need to get the color from the color picker. but i am not even able to open the color picker so need to remove the 13 version package and need to install the version 14 so can anyone tell me how can i do this?.

Comment: `npm uninstall  ngx-color-picker` then `npm install  ngx-color-picker@14` do this in the location of your package.json

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the version 13 of color picker

> npm uninstall ngx-color-picker

Now you can install the whatever version of the package you want using @x.x version

> npm install ngx-color-picker@14